# How to stop or pause animation in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to stop or pause the animation of a rectangle using **FabricJs**. However i tried to google a documentation, there is no much information on how to achieve it. I would appreciate any help

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});

var hasAnimationStarted = false;
document.getElementById('button').onclick = startAnimation;
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fill: "#FF0000",
  stroke: "#000",
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
});
canvas.add(rect);

function startAnimation() {
  if (hasAnimationStarted === false) {
    hasAnimationStarted === true;
    document.getElementById('button').innerText = 'Stop Animation';

    rect.animate({
      left: 250,
    }, {
      onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      duration: 6000,
      onComplete: function() {
        hasAnimationStarted === false;
        document.getElementById('button').innerText = 'Start Animation';
      },
      abort: function() {

      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
<button id="button">
  Start Animation
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a truthy value from `abort` method of animation, it will stop the animation.

***DEMO***

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  selection: false
});

let hasAnimationStarted = false;
document.getElementById('startAnim').onclick = startAnimation;

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fill: "#FF0000",
  stroke: "#000",
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
});
canvas.add(rect);

function startAnimation() {
  if (hasAnimationStarted) {
    stopAnimation();
  } else {
    hasAnimationStarted = true;
    document.getElementById('startAnim').innerText = 'Stop Animation';
    rect.animate({
      left: 250,
    }, {
      onChange: canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas),
      duration: 6000,
      onComplete: stopAnimation,
      abort: () => !hasAnimationStarted
    });
  }
}

function stopAnimation() {
  hasAnimationStarted = false;
  document.getElementById('startAnim').innerText = 'Start Animation';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
<button id="startAnim">
  Start Animation
</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand well why it should return `!hasAnimationStarted` appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @Xris if you return true from abort condition, it will stop the animation. As we are setting hasAnimationStarted to false on stop, so `!hasAnimationStarted` will be true.

Comment: Appriate a lot for your help

Comment: This doesn't allow for resuming animation after it has been paused.